# pandas dataframe overlapping time data on plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got this code generating the figure below.

in

```
yearly_data = { 2021: <..series..> , 2022: <..series..>}
print(type(yearly_data[2021]))
```

out

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

in

```
df = pd.DataFrame(yearly_data)
print(df.axes)
```

out

```
[DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-04', '2011-01-05', '2011-01-06', '2011-01-07',
               '2011-01-10', '2011-01-11', '2011-01-12', '2011-01-13',
               '2011-01-14', '2011-01-18',
               ...
               '2021-03-25', '2021-03-26', '2021-03-29', '2021-03-30',
               '2021-03-31', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-05', '2021-04-06',
               '2021-04-07', '2021-04-08'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=2572, freq=None), Int64Index([2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011], dtype='int64')]
```

in

```
title = 'comparison of yearly data'
plot = df.plot(figsize=(25,25), title=title)
figure = plot.get_figure()
figure.savefig(title + '.pdf')
```

out

[image]

basically every year data is plotted on the same axis and it's on the side of the other years, I'd like every year line to be on top of the others, so that it's easy to visually compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by `groupby` the month-day from the index and use `first` that would align all the years on the same date without the year:

```
#toy data
np.random.seed(12)
yearly_data = {
    2021:pd.Series(np.random.randint(40,50, size=365), 
                   index = pd.date_range('2021-01-01','2021-12-31',freq='d')),
    2020:pd.Series(np.random.randint(30,45, size=366), 
                   index = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-12-31',freq='d'))
}
# put data together
df = pd.DataFrame(yearly_data)

# here groupby and first
df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%m-%d')).first().plot()
```

Another possibility is to create another dictionary with the series with the index independent of the year, then `df.plot` will give the same output

```
yearly_data_MD = {}
for year, ser in yearly_data.items():
    ser_ = ser.copy()
    ser_.index = ser_.index.strftime('%m-%d')
    yearly_data_MD[year] = ser_
df = pd.DataFrame(yearly_data_MD)
df.plot()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works pretty nicely, though my data index contains only weekdays (mo-fr) so the resulting chart is full of holes. and very difficult to understand [see here](https://imgur.com/a/rg1kMGS) any ways to get the lines more "complete"?

Comment: @DonGiulio it depends on what you want exactly, but you could `interpolate` to "complete" the line with a line, so try `df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%m-%d')).first().interpolate().plot()`, same idea with the second method is possible

Comment: fantastic, interpolation did the trick, thanks